# cpdef in Cython tutorials not working

Tags: cython

I am new to cython. I have one source code file `hello.pyx`:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
     cpdef double sin(double x)
```

and, my `setup.py` file is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules=[
    Extension("hello",
              sources=["hello.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"] # Unix-like specific
    )
]

setup(
name = "Demos",
ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)
)
```

Then I compiled it to an `.so`.

But, when I `import hello`, I don't get the `hello.sin` function.

So what's the purpose of "Here is a Cython module that provides direct access to the C `sin()` function for Python code:" written in the tutorial?

I am following the [official tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html#external-declarations) on external declarations.

Results for running cythoning:

```
Compiling hello.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing hello.pyx
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall-Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/pool/software/python/python27plus-ibm/include/python2.7 -c hello.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/hello.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/hello.o -L/proj/dist/sandbox/miniconda/lib -lm -lpython2.7 -o /home/shaowu/Documents/cython_play/hello.so
```

Comment: So the module gets imported but there's no `sin` function in it? If you try accessing `hello.sin` you get an `AttributeError`?

Comment: @Jim Correct. When I do `dir(hello)`, there is no `sin`, I don't know why...

Comment: I'd check the version you're using. My impression is that this was added a couple of years ago so perhaps you're out of date.

Comment: It could be a reason. My cython version is 0.20.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidW stated, this is most likely due to you using an old version of Cython. In versions < `0.22` your `setup.py` script, according to documentation, [should look like this](http://cython.org/docs/0.21/src/tutorial/external.html#dynamic-linking):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
    Extension("demo",
              ["demo.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"]) # Unix-like specific
]

setup(
  name = "Demos",
  cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Either use that or, ideally, [install the latest version](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem on my laptop, here are the steps I did:

- `cd` to the directory containing `hello.pyx`, `setup.py` and `test.py`
- `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`
- `python test.py`

This returns:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__test__', 'sin']
0.479425538604203
```

With `test.py` containing:

```
import hello

print(dir(hello))
print(hello.sin(0.5))
```